# emr-dynamodb-connector control/throttle the writes to DDB (Throughput exceeds the current throughput limit for your account.)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I am trying to write 1 TB / 30 million documents to DDB table.
DDB table is set for On-demand capacity.
For that i am using `emr-dynamodb-connector` by running spark job on EMR cluster. Code looks like below

```
JobConf ddbConfWrite = new JobConf(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration());
ddbConfWrite.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", tableName);
ddbConfWrite.set("dynamodb.throughput.write.percent", "0.5");
ddbConfWrite.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat");
ddbConfWrite.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat");

ddbInsertFormattedRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(ddbConfWrite);
```

but i while job is writing it is eventually trying to insert the documents at fast rate that is eventually hitting account limit. below is the exception i am getting

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.RequestLimitExceededException: Throughput exceeds the current throughput limit for your account. Please contact AWS Support at https://aws.amazon.com/support request a limit increase (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: RequestLimitExceeded

Answer (score 0):

You can file a ticket as suggested to raise the soft limit on account capacity. It’s just there as a sanity check that you actually mean to run at that capacity (and incur that cost).

Comment: yeah that is an option, but that limit will be breached too. So looking for an option where we can control the writes we are hitting

Comment: So why are you in On Demand mode? Have you tried provisioning the table at the rate you desire?

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the work around, but i dont have admin access to table to change it to provisioned and turn it back to on demand